# Why there is a difference in preview and the design?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to use the predefined gradient styles where i found one design and applied it.
Look at the below image.

[image]

Could anyone suggest me why there is a difference between the preview and the real image?
(The black border internally)

The question is simple. Why there's a difference between the preview and the actual image that's being rendered.

Comment: If you are asking why there is a difference in the small preview window it is because the preview window is not an exact rendering of the effect.

Comment: Is that the fault of photoshop or am i missing something to make it render perfectly?

Comment: It's a part of Photoshop, don't make your decisions based on that small preview box, you should instead check the preview option and preview your effect on the artboard (As it looks like you were already doing). Then, you can see the effect of changes accurately.

Comment: ok. Can you suggest me how to remove that black border. Am unable to find where it came from

Comment: It is a product of one of the options you are using. If you have any more questions, I'd be happy to walk you through it in chat, but I don't want to muddy this comment section up with a back and forth.

Comment: Yeah sure. Even i would like to chat. Can i get a link to join you.

Comment: You can remove the preview black border by pressing Ctrl + Shift + H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "black border internally" is the path of the shape being highlighted.

[image: shape]

You can click the blank area on the Path Panel to de-highlight the path:

[image: de-highlight]

Or switch to another tool, like the Move Tool.

Comment: Hey i think that's the issue. Thanks for suggesting me this. I had to switch my layer so remove that black border.